# How to prevent Google bot to crawl a specific page

Tags: apache

I have a page that contains many links which I don't want Google to crawl.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `robots.txt` file in your HTTP root. If you have a site at http://domain.com , put `robots.txt` to where you can load it at http://domain.com/robots.txt .

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /somewhere_i_dont_want_google_to_crawl.php
Disallow: /dont_crawl_this_directory/
```

Here is a real practical [example](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) on the Stack Overflow website.

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly is "HTTP root"? How can I check if it is actually taking effect?

Comment: I made an edit and clarified it. Google has an article about robots.txt : http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=35237&rd=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `robots.txt` in your HTTP root, and you can also use a meta tag (if your page is HTML) to stop it too:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex" />
```

See [this website](http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout out the [robots.txt file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt)

But don't do what the idiot admin at `whitehouse.gov` did and list in this file everything they wanted to keep secret

Oh and last thing - don't trust it - it is "supposed to stop a crawler" but I would not be a legal case on it